# How to show different questions and answers in different screens based on whatever is inside the json file?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to create a lot of screens and each screens has their own questions and answers from the json file.
I'm fairly new to python and I can't seem to get a work around to this problem.
Any suggestions would very much be appreciated.

test.py

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition, WipeTransition
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import (StringProperty, NumericProperty, ObjectProperty,
                         ListProperty, DictProperty, BooleanProperty)
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.touchripple import TouchRippleBehavior
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore
from kivy.lang import global_idmap, Builder
import time
from kivy.storage.jsonstore import JsonStore


class SubjectsLayout(GridLayout):
    question_text = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SubjectsLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.store = JsonStore('projectdata.json')
        self.retrieve_questions()
        self.retrieve_answers()

    def retrieve_questions(self):
        q = list(self.store.keys())

        self.question_text = q[0]

    def retrieve_answers(self):
        pass

class NavTray1(BoxLayout):
    pass


class RippleButton(TouchRippleBehavior, Button):

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        collide_point = self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y)
        if collide_point:
            touch.grab(self)
            self.transparency = self.background_color[3]  
            self.background_color[3] = 0.5  
            self.ripple_show(touch)
            self.dispatch('on_press')
            return True
        return False

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            touch.ungrab(self)
            self.ripple_fade()
            def defer_release(dt):
                self.background_color[3] = self.transparency  
                self.dispatch('on_release')
            Clock.schedule_once(defer_release, self.ripple_duration_out)
            return True
        return False

class SurveyHeader(GridLayout):
    pass

class QuestionsScreen1(Screen):
    pass

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):    
    def new_page(self):
        if self.current is 'start':
            s = QuestionsScreen1(name='Question 1', id = 'Question1')
            self.add_widget(s)
            self.current = 'Question 1'
        elif self.current is 'Question 1':           
                s = QuestionsScreen1(name='Question 2', id = 'Question2')
                self.add_widget(s)
                self.current = 'Question 2'
        elif self.current is 'Question 2':             
                s = QuestionsScreen1(name='Question 3', id = 'Question3')
                self.add_widget(s)
                self.current = 'Question 3'



Login = Builder.load_string('''
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import SoundLoader kivy.core.audio.SoundLoader
#: import ScrollEffect kivy.effects.scroll.ScrollEffect
#: import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

MyScreenManager:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    QuestionsScreen1:

<NavTray1>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    padding: '5dp'
    spacing: '5dp'
    canvas.before:
        Color: 
            rgb: .1, .1, .1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
    RippleButton:
        color: [0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 1]
        size_hint: (.33, None)
        height: '80dp'
        text: 'Back'

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size_hint: (.33, 1.0)
        id: custom

    RippleButton:
        color: [6/255, 114/255, 0, 1]
        size_hint: (.33, None)
        height: '80dp'
        text: 'Forward'
        background_color: [28/138, 1, 35/138, 0.5]
        on_release : app.root.new_page()
        on_release : app.root.transition = SlideTransition(direction='left')




<QuestionsScreen1>:
    name: "start"
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        size: root.size
        pos: root.pos
        SurveyHeader:
            size_hint: (1.0, None)
            height: '90dp'
            id: header
        ScrollView:
            size_hint: (1.0, None)
            height: root.height - header.height - navtray.height
            SubjectsLayout:
            id: subjects
        NavTray1:
            size_hint: (1.0, None)
            id: navtray
            height: '90dp'

<SurveyHeader>:
    cols: 1
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: (.10, .1, .1)
        Rectangle:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos

<SubjectsLayout>:
    cols: 1
Label:
    size_hint_y : 0.25
    text: root.question_text
    font_size: "30dp"
GridLayout:
    cols: 2
    rows: 4
    size_hint_y : 0.75
    Label:
        text: 'a'
        font_size: "20dp" 
        size_hint_x : 0.8
    CheckBox:
        group: 'answer_group'
        size_hint_x : 0.2
    Label:
        text: 'b'
        font_size: "20dp"
        size_hint_x : 0.8
    CheckBox:
        group: 'answer_group'
        size_hint_x : 0.2
    Label:
        text: 'c'
        font_size: "20dp"
        size_hint_x : 0.8
    CheckBox:
        group: 'answer_group'
        size_hint_x : 0.2
    Label:
        text: 'd'
        font_size: "20dp"
        size_hint_x : 0.8
    CheckBox:
        group: 'answer_group'
        size_hint_x : 0.2


''')


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Login


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

projectdata.json

```
{"Question 1": {"A": "1", "B": "2", "C": "3", "D": "4"}, "Question 2": {"A": "5", "B": "6", "C": "7", "D": "8"}}
```

I expect each screen should correctly follow the questions and answers from the json file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Question 2

> I was wondering if its possible to have like 1st screen getting
>   question 1, second screen getting question 2, so on and so forth like
>   in the Json file. I'm trying to create a lot more questions so is
>   there a faster way to this?

## Solution 2

- Use the name of the screen e.g. `screenmanager.current`

### py - snippets

```
    def retrieve_questions(self, dt=0):
        if self.store.count() > 0:
            self.question_text = App.get_running_app().root.current

            for key, val in self.store.get(self.question_text).items():
                if isinstance(self.ids[key], Label):
                    self.ids[key].text = str(val)
...
    def new_page(self):
        if self.current == 'Question 1':
            s = QuestionsScreen1(name='Question 2', id='Question2')
            self.add_widget(s)
            self.current = 'Question 2'
        elif self.current == 'Question 2':
            s = QuestionsScreen1(name='Question 3', id='Question3')
            self.add_widget(s)
            self.current = 'Question 3'
```

### kv - snippets

```
<QuestionsScreen1>:
    name: "Question 1"
```

## Output 2

[image: Question 1]
[image: Question 2]

## Question 1

- Add `ids` to each `Label` to be the same as in the Json file.
- Since `ids` of inner widget may not be available during the inner widget's `__init__` function, use `Clock.schedule_once()` to invoke `self.retrieve_questions`
- Check for non-empty Json store

## kv file - Snippets

```
<SubjectsLayout>:
    cols: 1
    Label:
        size_hint_y : 0.25
        text: root.question_text
        font_size: "30dp"
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        rows: 4
        size_hint_y : 0.75
        Label:
            id: A
            text: 'a'
            font_size: "20dp"
            size_hint_x : 0.8
        CheckBox:
            group: 'answer_group'
            size_hint_x : 0.2
        Label:
            id: B
            text: 'b'
            font_size: "20dp"
            size_hint_x : 0.8
        CheckBox:
            group: 'answer_group'
            size_hint_x : 0.2
        Label:
            id: C
            text: 'c'
            font_size: "20dp"
            size_hint_x : 0.8
        CheckBox:
            group: 'answer_group'
            size_hint_x : 0.2
        Label:
            id: D
            text: 'd'
            font_size: "20dp"
            size_hint_x : 0.8
        CheckBox:
            group: 'answer_group'
            size_hint_x : 0.2
```

## Py - Snippets

```
class SubjectsLayout(GridLayout):
    question_text = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SubjectsLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.store = JsonStore('projectdata.json')
        Clock.schedule_once(self.retrieve_questions, 1)

    def retrieve_questions(self, dt):
        if self.store.count() > 0:
            q = list(self.store.keys())

            self.question_text = q[0]
            for key, val in self.store.get(q[0]).items():
                if isinstance(self.ids[key], Label):
                    self.ids[key].text = str(val)
```

## Output

[image: Result]

Comment: Hi ikolim, thanks for your reply. But I was wondering if its possible to have like 1st screen getting question 1, second screen getting question 2, so on and so forth like in the Json file. I'm trying to create a lot more questions so is there a faster way to this?